# How to copy a math output to clipboard in Python?

Tags: python

I'm super new to Python so I'm wondering if someone can help me out or link me to an appropriate post that explains this?

What I would like to do is

```
9999**9999
```

in Python Terminal, then copy the output directly to my clipboard or sent to a file.

I tried in Batch using

```
py 9999**9999 >>pythonoutput.txt
```

but only got an error of

```
python.exe: can't open file '9999**9999': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

and not sure how I could make that work either.

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
python -c print(9999*9999) > outfile.txt
```

You might want to use `py` instead of `python` there since you seem to have your executable renamed.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Also you wouldn't happen to be the Wiggy that helped Moderate a large Discord server with myself and a few others about a month ago? We hit 3k members then got closed?

Comment: A month ago, I was trying to figure out if I'm more of an idiot than my dog is. So, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to write (append) to a file:-

```
obj=open("yourfile.txt","a+") #open a reference to your file, in append mode. (Use 'w' for write, and 'r' for read if you ever need to)
obj.write("your chars, numbers or whatever here") #use this as many times as you want before closing
obj.close() #close your reference once you're done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sent to result to file is much easier than to clipboard.

**In the python terminal**,you can do this:

```
with open("/home/my/output","w") as file:#start a file object for writing
    file.write(str(9999*9999))#write the content
```